# Center absolute content inside an relative div

Tags: html, css

[image]How to center the span content within a div, and to add that there is a dynamic div height depending on how many rows appear?

CSS:

```
div {
    position: relative; 
    height: auto; 
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
span { 
    position: absolute; 
    width: 10px; 
    height: 10px; 
    background-color: #003858;
}
```

This is the html content:

```
<div>
 <span style="left: 12px; top: 0px;">&nbsp;</span>
 <span style="left: 24px; top: 0px;">&nbsp;</span>
 <span style="left: 36px; top: 0px;">&nbsp;</span>
 <span style="left: 48px; top: 0px;">&nbsp;</span>
 <span style="left: 60px; top: 0px;">&nbsp;</span>                  
 <span style="left: 12px; top: 15px;">&nbsp;</span>
 <span style="left: 24px; top: 15px;">&nbsp;</span>
 <span style="left: 36px; top: 15px;">&nbsp;</span>
 <span style="left: 48px; top: 15px;">&nbsp;</span>
 <span style="left: 60px; top: 15px;">&nbsp;</span>                 
 <span style="left: 12px; top: 30px;">&nbsp;</span>
 <span style="left: 24px; top: 30px;">&nbsp;</span>
 <span style="left: 36px; top: 30px;">&nbsp;</span>
 <span style="left: 48px; top: 30px;">&nbsp;</span>
 <span style="left: 60px; top: 30px;">&nbsp;</span>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: you are manually setting the `left` position of each `span` element. What do you mean you want to center them?

Comment: When all content within the div is absolute, the div will have no width or height. You cannot center anything inside of a div with no width and no height.

Comment: something like this http://postimg.org/image/8vn7pwx7p/

Comment: It looks like you're doing a table using span elements for which you set the position of each columns and rows. Euh??? Why not do a table using <table>?? The image you posted shows a table with black boxes and white borders no?

Comment: For every span I dynamically add top and left position so this is ok I don't want to change that logic..the image is just an simple example, take a look another one where I have large number of span...

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your container div style:

```
left: 50%;
```

Checkout this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ramudezowe/1/)

You may try to adjust the percentage according to your spans total width.

Comment: ahah, @sємsєм , beat me to it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin-left:50; /*50% is about halfway*/` to your `div`.

**EDIT**

`left` works pretty much the same as `margin-left`.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't absolutely position, it isn't very dynamic unless you were building the html from an exact model.

CSS

```
#container {
    width:100%;
}
#blocks {
    margin: auto auto;
    width: 80px;
    background-color: #ff8200;
    line-height: 0;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}
span { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px; 
    height: 10px;
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
    background-color: #003858;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="blocks">
  <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
 </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yeh28ja1/

This way you can just add spans and increase the width of `#blocks` as needed, without doing a bunch of math. But depending on what your application is doing, this may be counter-productive. We really don't know enough about what you're trying to do.

Updated with some absolute positioning centering techniques.

https://jsfiddle.net/yeh28ja1/2/

Notice the use of negative margins, which will depend on the width of your absolute positioned element.

Comment: Every span has left and top position within a div, so all content should be somehow centered no matter how span content there are (big picture is an real example)

Comment: @cvelinho see my example, you can center the div that contains the spans, but you need to give it width and height. The div's parent needs to be full width as well, so that its children may be centered.

Comment: yes this is quite ok, but the problem is that I have to set absolute position for span elemen (it could be also div or td)